# Python: How do I extract the year from a date

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe and in one of the columns it has the date, for example, 1/7/13. I want to extract the year out of this. How would I do it?

I've tried

`years_2 = df3.pivot_table(index=['ACCIDENT_DATE'], aggfunc ='size')`

`print(years_2)`

but I get the recurrence of the date but I want to count just the number of times that an year occurs. Something like this:

`Year`

`2013   1000`

`2014   59882`

`2015  23232`

Answer (score 1):

datetime.strptime will convert a string to datetime object based on the format you want. Then you can get year attribute from this object like below:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('1/7/13', '%d/%m/%y').year
```

Comment: After this @kunal4014 need to do a for loop and count the occurrences for the years by making a dictionary of ```year : occurrence```

Answer (score 0):

If `df3.ACCIDENT_DATE` is of dtype datetime, then you can get the components of the date with `.dt` accessors

```
d = df3.ACCIDENT_DATE

# return series of dtype int
year = d.dt.year
month = d.dt.month
day = d.dt.day
```

If it has a time component

```
# return series of dtype datetime
date_ = d.dt.date
time_ = d.dt.time

# return series of dtype int
h = d.dt.hour
m = d.dt.minute
```

And many more in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#datetimelike-properties)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) function to get number of times year occurred.

```
years_2["ACCIDENT_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(years_2["ACCIDENT_DATE"])
counts = years_2["ACCIDENT_DATE"].dt.year.value_counts()
```

to get year as a separate column

```
years_2["YEAR"] = years_2["ACCIDENT_DATE"].dt.year
```